# What is the tight binding Hamiltonian for Graphene in terms of the Pauli Matrices?

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene, tight-binding

I have been unable to find an expression for the tight binding Hamiltonian of Graphene in terms of the Pauli Matrices. Please share any reference available. Thank You

Comment: Check the bernevig and hughes textbook

Comment: It says that for isotropic hopping parameters each being equal to 1, the Hamiltonian can be expressed as $k_x \sigma_x +k_y \sigma_y$. Doesn't this give a slightly different form of the Hamiltonian compared to what is shown https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73720/graphenes-tight-binding-hamiltonian?rq=1

Comment: It looks like it exactly matches the epxression for $H_{monolayer}$, no?